# How can I put on Parse.com the content of an EditText?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm trying to create a "Contacts" activity where the user can write something on an EditText widget and then by pressing "send" Parse.com will create a file .txt and upload it on my parse class online. The only problem is that I can't actually tell the script to "read" what's in the EditText. Let me show you:

```
 public void send(View view)//this is the onclick "send" button 
{


    byte[] data = "text to send".getBytes();// In this way parse.com will write "text to send" in the .txt file. Here's the problem: i can't figure out how to tell parse to take what's in the edit text widget and write it inside the .txt.

    ParseFile file = new ParseFile("contact.txt", data);
    file.saveInBackground();

    ParseObject contacts = new ParseObject("Contacts");
    contacts.put("contactName", "File");
    contacts.put("contactResumeFile", file);
    contacts.saveInBackground();
}
```

Any thoughts? any help will be happily accepted :)

Comment: Where is you edit text?

Comment: https://parse.com/docs/android/guide

Comment: EditText editabletext;            ---- oncreate ----> editabletext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have to upload it as .txt file, you can use getText().toString() and then upload it using saveInBackground()

Comment: Thanks, I did it before to read this comment. That's how I did it, thanks :D